# In the production of antiprotons with an iridium target, does the mass of the target matters?

Tags: antimatter

In CERN, 0.0003% of the protons that collide with a 0.01 kg iridium plate result in antiprotons.

Wouldn't increasing the mass of the plate result in a higher collision rate? Wouldn't be proportional?

I mean, I assume that the more iridium, the more protons in the plate, and the more protons in the plate, the more likely is that the shot protons collide with a proton and an antiproton is produced.

Comment: Its is much more complicated  . See    https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/IPAC2012/papers/WEPPD030.pdf?n=IPAC2012/papers/WEPPD030.pdf   "The emphasis is on the optimization of the
accumulation rate of antiprotons to maximize the
expected peak and average luminosity for the experiment. "

Comment: BTW one should give links or references for numerical statements in the questions.

Comment: The incoming protons only go so far into a chunk of material. Any antiprotons produced need to get out of the material to be useful. The cross section is only so big (and proton energy dependent, as the proton loses energy going through the material). A complicated optimization problem.

Comment: Note that the statement isn't "only 0.0003% of protons are stopped by the plate/collide with something in the plate." The statement is "only 0.0003% turn into antiprotons." Do you know if the problem is that most protons aren't stopped at all? In which case I'd presume its about how far antiprotons can travel through metal at that energy. Otherwise maybe most protons are lost but only a small fraction make antiprotons. Upvoting because I work in this building and I don't know the answer.